java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character ' ' for QUERY_PARAM
I am trying to upgrade spring boot 2.3 to 3.2 , i am getting below error if query parameter contain space (' ') Character. i tried several things but did not find any solution yet.. Can anyone help me on this.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character ' ' for QUERY_PARAM in "choco test"
        at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.verifyUriComponent(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:422)
        at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.lambda$verify$4(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:390)
        at org.springframework.util.UnmodifiableMultiValueMap.lambda$forEach$0(UnmodifiableMultiValueMap.java:115)
        at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
        at org.springframework.util.MultiValueMapAdapter.forEach(MultiValueMapAdapter.java:179)
        at org.springframework.util.UnmodifiableMultiValueMap.forEach(UnmodifiableMultiValueMap.java:115)
        at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.verify(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:387)
        at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.<init>(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:146)
        at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.buildInternal(UriComponentsBuilder.java:451)
        at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.build(UriComponentsBuilder.java:439)
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.handler.ProxyExchangeHandlerFunction.handle(ProxyExchangeHandlerFunction.java:76)
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.handler.HandlerFunctions$LookupProxyExchangeHandlerFunction.handle(HandlerFunctions.java:98)
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.filter.LoadBalancerFilterFunctions.lambda$lb$5(LoadBalancerFilterFunctions.java:112)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$andThen$0(HandlerFilterFunction.java:58)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$ofRequestProcessor$3(HandlerFilterFunction.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$andThen$0(HandlerFilterFunction.java:58)
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.filter.LoadBalancerFilterFunctions.lambda$lb$5(LoadBalancerFilterFunctions.java:112)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$andThen$0(HandlerFilterFunction.java:58)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$ofRequestProcessor$3(HandlerFilterFunction.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$andThen$0(HandlerFilterFunction.java:58)
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.filter.LoadBalancerFilterFunctions.lambda$lb$5(LoadBalancerFilterFunctions.java:112)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$andThen$0(HandlerFilterFunction.java:58)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$ofRequestProcessor$3(HandlerFilterFunction.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$andThen$1(HandlerFilterFunction.java:59)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$andThen$1(HandlerFilterFunction.java:59)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$andThen$1(HandlerFilterFunction.java:59)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$andThen$1(HandlerFilterFunction.java:59)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$andThen$1(HandlerFilterFunction.java:59)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$apply$2(HandlerFilterFunction.java:70)
        at com.test.Rouconffiguration.lambda$routeGssRequest$1(RouteConfiguration.java:103)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$andThen$0(HandlerFilterFunction.java:58)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$ofRequestProcessor$3(HandlerFilterFunction.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$andThen$1(HandlerFilterFunction.java:59)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$apply$2(HandlerFilterFunction.java:70)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.support.HandlerFunctionAdapter.handle(HandlerFunctionAdapter.java:108)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.filter.WeightCalculatorFilter.doFilter(WeightCalculatorFilter.java:229)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.filter.FormFilter.doFilter(FormFilter.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:108)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:384)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:904)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)

i tried to update spring boot to 3.2.9 but still not working.i tried to upgrade to little lower version of spring boot like 3.1.6 but still the same issue.

It is an illegal char and should be encoded.

would you mind sharing the UriComponentsBuilder part where you are building the URL.
